# Как найти число определенной длины?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Нужно найти строку длиной в 5 цифр, как это можно сделать на питоне?

```
09876
123456789
abc77777abc
78 980 1234
2222 3 33333
```

что должно быть найдено в итоге:

```
09876
77777
33333
```

можно как-то это сократить?

```
import re
    
path = open("test.txt").read()
a = re.findall('(\d+)', path)
b = []
for res in a:
    if len(res) == 5:
        b.append(res)
print b
```

Comment: 0.... -  это строка из 5 цифр, а не число.

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: ** Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. ** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно:

```
print([x for x in re.findall('(\d+)', path) if len(x) == 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = """09876
123456789
abc77777abc
78 980 1234
2222 3 33333"""

res = re.findall(r'(?:^|[\D\b])(\d{5})(?:$|[\D\b\n\r])', text)

print(res)
```

результат:

```
['09876', '77777', '33333']
```